# GAE Go — How to use GetMulti with non-existent entity keys?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, go

I've found myself needing to do a `GetMulti` operation with an array of keys for which some entities exist, but some do not.

My current code, below, returns an error (`datastore: no such entity`).

`err := datastore.GetMulti(c, keys, infos)`

So how can I do this? I'd use a "get or insert" method, but there isn't one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

GetMulti can return a [`appengine.MultiError`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine#MultiError) in this case. Loop through that and look for [`datastore.ErrNoSuchEntity`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/datastore#pkg-variables). For example:

```
if err := datastore.GetMulti(c, keys, dst); err != nil {
    if me, ok := err.(appengine.MultiError); ok {
        for i, merr := range me {
            if merr == datastore.ErrNoSuchEntity {
                // keys[i] is missing
            }
        }
    } else {
        return err
    }
}
```

Comment: you could shorten that block if you used a type assertion. if me, ok := err.(appengine.MultiError); ok { for { ... } }

Comment: Thanks. Is that what you meant?

Comment: yep you can drop the else clause as well and just return err for one less line too :-)

Comment: In the else case there's a real error and we want to indicate some problem, so I think it makes sense to keep it.

Comment: Ahhh yeah since you still need access to the err object. Good point.

Answer (score 2):

I know this topic is up for more than a few days, but I like to post an alternative, using *type switch*.

```
if err := datastore.GetMulti(c, keys, dst); err != nil {
  switch errt := err.(type) {
  case appengine.MultiError:
    for ix, e := range errt {
      if e == datastore.ErrNoSuchEntity {
        // keys[ix] not found
      } else if e != nil {
        // keys[ix] have error "e"
      }
    }
  default:
    // datastore returned an error that is not a multi-error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd throw my answer in to display another usecase. The following will take in any number of keys and return all the valid keys only.

```
// Validate keys
var validKeys []*ds.Key
if err := c.DB.GetMulti(ctx, tempKeys, dst); err != nil {
    if me, ok := err.(ds.MultiError); ok {
        for i, merr := range me {
            if merr == ds.ErrNoSuchEntity {
                continue
            }
            validKeys = append(validKeys, tempKeys[i])
        }
    } else {
        return "", err
    }
} else {
    // All tempKeys are valid
    validKeys = append(validKeys, tempKeys...)
}
```